# error en TRANSACTION (firestore) despues de actualizar plugins en FLUTTER

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

actualmente venia modificando el código de una aplicación y luego de actualizar android vi que no podia compilar mi app en el celular , cuestion era un error producido por plugins desactualizados. Segun entendi hubo un cambio importante en todos los plugins de firebase y tuve que actualizar todos , luego de esto pude compilar la app en mi celular. Pero observe que al hacer la primera compilacion la app crashea indicando que una transaction realizada por el metodo getToken "de firebase messaging" estaba fallando porque no puede hacer el get de un documento con valor nulo. Lo raro es que solo lo hace en la primera compilacion. si saco la operacion , compilo , la habilito y recompilo la operacion actualiza con exito el valor pasado en mi base de firestore. Los prints muestran que obtiene los datos de token y _currentUid sin problemas.

Me podran ayudar? tambien veo varias advertencias nuevas en los logs.

Intenté cambiar la operacion para intentar capturar el error pero supuestamente la referencia al documento la obtiene sin problemas en modo debug.

ANDROID Build Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // <- Add this line
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Operacion que venia utilizando

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      print(token+'----TOKEN');
      print(this._currentUID+'----USERID');
      final DocumentReference postRef = Firestore.instance.collection('usuarios').document(this._currentUID);
      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
            DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
            if (postSnapshot.exists) {
              await tx.update(postRef,
                  <String, dynamic>{
                    'token': token,
                  });
            }
          });
    });
```

Al usar esta el error es el mismo

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      assert(uid!='');
      DocumentReference postRef = Firestore.instance.document('usuarios/'+uid);
      if(postRef!=null){
        Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
          try{
            DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
            if (postSnapshot.exists) {
              await tx.update(postRef,
                  <String, dynamic>{
                    'token': token,
                  });
            }
          }on PlatformException catch(e){
            print(e.message+e.details+e.code);
          }
        });

      }else{
        print("error null");
      }
    });
```

LOG--> PUEDEN VER LOS DOS RESULTADOS QUE OBTENGO , MAYORMENTE SIEMPRE CRASHEA CON EL ERROR QUE DICE "LOST CONNECTION".

```
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Nexus 6P...
//-----------------------ESTE ERROR??-----------------------//
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call
Builder#setApplicationName.
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
//---------------------------------------------------------//
I/flutter ( 3822): usuario logueadoQadbWIiq7PZgAXU6XBW3Uh5TvdB2
I/flutter ( 3822): valueee:null
I/flutter ( 3822): ingresando a home
//-----------------------ESTE ERROR??-----------------------//
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 3822): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
//---------------------------------------------------------//
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
I/flutter ( 3822): Service status: true
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
//-----------------------ESTE ERROR??-----------------------//
W/DynamiteModule( 3822): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 3822): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 3822): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
//---------------------------------------------------------//
I/flutter ( 3822): 
dxKrtmtSNmo:APA91bHDt6tUhdxyrvIEIFvsuBri29KtQBJqVoQ8ZU90Cmncn7ZDjpueXKKJiCWrC_f4fBNKpvHp7T-DS6cYF3sIEIFvsuBri29KtQBJJ5X98lk8lw0H4v7tLvt6Iw7McrGTc----TOKEN
I/flutter ( 3822): QadbJqVoQ8ZU90CXBW3Uh5TvdB2---USERID
//-----------------------ESTE ERROR??-----------------------//
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Can't mmap dex file /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar!classes.dex directly; please zipalign to 4 bytes. Falling back to extracting file.
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Can't mmap dex file /system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar!classes.dex directly; please zipalign to 4 bytes. Falling back to extracting file.
I/pp1.salepartid( 3822): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto( 3822): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 284 native methods...
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (light greylist, reflection)
I/ProviderInstaller( 3822): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
//---------------------------------------------------------//
I/flutter ( 3822): Permission: true
I/FirebaseRemoteConfig( 3822): Fetch succeeded!
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
I/FirebaseRemoteConfig( 3822): Fetch succeeded!
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
W/zze     ( 3822): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
I/flutter ( 3822): valueee:null
I/flutter ( 3822): valueee:null
//---------------------NO ENTIENDO ESTE ACCESING HIDDEN TAMPOCO--------//
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (light greylist, reflection)
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, linking)
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, linking)
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (light greylist, JNI)
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (light greylist, linking)
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (light greylist, linking)
W/pp1.salepartid( 3822): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
////----------MAYORMENTE TIRA ESTE ERROR QUE CIERRA LA APP---------------////
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648): Process: com.app1.salepartido, PID: 4648
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.get(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$4.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$4.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:392)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4648):    ... 4 more
I/Process ( 4648): Sending signal. PID: 4648 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

////-----------------MUY POCAS VECES TIRA ESTE TIMEOUT-----------------////
I/flutter ( 3822): Info MAP: -34.5516819
I/flutter ( 3822): STA ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 3822): sin informacion
I/flutter ( 3822): Info MAP: -34.5516819
I/flutter ( 3822): STA ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 3822): sin informacion
I/flutter ( 3822): Info MAP: -34.5516819
I/flutter ( 3822): STA ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 3822): sin informacion
I/flutter ( 3822): STA ConnectionState.done
I/flutter ( 3822): con info
E/flutter ( 3822): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing transaction, Timed out waiting for Task, null)
E/flutter ( 3822): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter ( 3822): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:302:33)
E/flutter ( 3822): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3822): #2      Firestore.runTransaction (package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart:116:10)
E/flutter ( 3822): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3822): #3      HomePageState.doAsyncStuff.<anonymous closure> (package:sale_partido/home.dart:196:26)
E/flutter ( 3822): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter ( 3822): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 3822): #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
E/flutter ( 3822): #7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
E/flutter ( 3822): #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
E/flutter ( 3822): #9      Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
E/flutter ( 3822): #10     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 3822): #11     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
E/flutter ( 3822): #12     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
E/flutter ( 3822): #13     FirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart)
E/flutter ( 3822): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3822): #14     HomePageState.doAsyncStuff (package:sale_partido/home.dart:191:24)
E/flutter ( 3822): #15     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
E/flutter ( 3822): #16     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter ( 3822): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 3822): #18     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
E/flutter ( 3822): #19     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
E/flutter ( 3822): #20     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
E/flutter ( 3822): #21     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
E/flutter ( 3822): #22     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 3822): #23     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
E/flutter ( 3822): #24     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
E/flutter ( 3822): #25     HomePageState._getCurrentUserID (package:sale_partido/home.dart)
E/flutter ( 3822): #26     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
E/flutter ( 3822): #27     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter ( 3822): #28     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 3822): #29     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
E/flutter ( 3822): #30     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
E/flutter ( 3822): #31     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
E/flutter ( 3822): #32     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
E/flutter ( 3822): #33     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 3822): #34     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
E/flutter ( 3822): #35     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
E/flutter ( 3822): #36     FirebaseAuth.currentUser (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart)
E/flutter ( 3822): #37     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
E/flutter ( 3822): #38     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter ( 3822): #39     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 3822): #40     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
E/flutter ( 3822): #41     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
E/flutter ( 3822): #42     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
E/flutter ( 3822): #43     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
E/flutter ( 3822): #44     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 3822): #45     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
E/flutter ( 3822): #46     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
E/flutter ( 3822): #47     MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
E/flutter ( 3822): #48     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
E/flutter ( 3822): #49     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter ( 3822): #50     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 3822): #51     _FutureL
```